# How to COUNT between a date range if nested within another formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to substitute '!!!!!!' for a formula to count the number of  `W`  in column  `P`  on sheet  `TRADE LOG`  between the dates of 01 Feb 2021 and 28 Feb 2021 in hardcoded format.

This is the current formula :

`=IF(COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"W",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)),"!!!!!!","")`

Could anyone suggest what needs to be added in order to achieve this?

To make this clearer, I want `F16` in `STATISTICS` to count the number of `W`'s in sheet `TRADE LOG` column `P` between the dates of 01 Feb 2021 and 28 Feb 2021. However, if there is none I would like `F16` to return a blank.

Comment: What did you mean with "hardcoded"? Are you not working with true datevalues? Currently you `IF()` does not make sense if you have your `COUNTIFS()` in there.

Comment: Hi JvdV, I assumed they were hardcoded, I stand corrected. I was under the impression I just needed to insert a formula in place of the '!!!!!!' , if that's not that case then I am unsure.

Comment: I think you can just use the `COUNTIFS()` as you have got it done. No need for `IF()`.

Comment: It just returns 'error with this formula' and i can't figure out why this is.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not you are working with true dates or just string values looking like dates?

Comment: I have just edited the question, it should give a clearer direction on what I am trying to do. The dates are manually put in ones, I'm not sure if this makes them true or string values?

Comment: Excel version 16.45

Comment: Oh right, 2019 version.

Comment: Typically you'd then use the `IF(<yourCountifs>=0,"",<yourCountifs>)` construct. Basically you'd do the same calculation twice.

Comment: Thanks, that makes some sense to me. I initially thought that's what I had done above, however now when I attempt to write the formula the way I want things to come out I get the same error in the formula. I think i am struggling to implement it with the dates.

Comment: Your `COUNTIFS()` looks fine. This is why I mentioned *are you **sure** you are working with true datevalues*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (i have tried to research this). I entered the dates manually into the formula if that's what you mean.

Comment: That's not what I mean. If everything in your formula seems correct but you still get an error it's time to look for answers elsewhere. For example in the data you are processing. Is **that** actually dates or just string values looking like dates?

Comment: The dates are auto-populated via VBA formulas and fill cell A1 when I enter data into A2. I have done this due to requiring static dates.